# MFC translucent dialog with black background

Tags: mfc, overlay, translucency

I want to implement such a dialog. When it pop up, the background color of its parent windows will become dark or masked. So what i did was to define another translucent window.

```
SetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
this->SetLayeredWindowAttributes(RGB(0,0,0), 128, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

But the translucent windows color is default windows color. I want it black. So I painted background black in

```
HBRUSH CDlgOverlay::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{
    return bkBrush;
}
```

The bkBrush is a black brush. But the translucent window disappear. So do you know what i need? A translucent window, but translucent black background color.

Answer (score 1):

I make it myself. Just need to modify one parameter.

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(RGB(0,0,0), 128, LWA_ALPHA);
```

I am so stupid.